# vscode snippets - items in an array

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have simple snippet:

```
- const ${1:listItems} = ["$3","$4", "$5", "$6"]

ul
  each ${2:item}, i in ${1:listItems} 
    li #{ ${2:item} } 
$0
```

now its set up to display 4 items ... is there a simple way how to fill items in an array if the number of items is unknown? (one time it can be 5 items another time it can be 12 items)
Do I just put:

```
- const ${1:listItems} = [$3]
```

and keep typing or is there another way how to add items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a separator character, in example I choose `|`, that is unlikely to be in an item, split argument `${3}` on this separator and enclose it in `"` or substitute it with `,`

Use this as the body of the snippet

```
    "body": [
      "- const ${1:listItems} = [${3/([^|]+)|([|])/${1:+\"}$1${1:+\"}${2:+, }/g}]",
      "",
      "  ul",
      "    each ${2:item}, i in ${1}",
      "    li #{ ${2} } ",
      "$0"]
```

Comment: can you give me an example of list? is it just `-const listItems = ["a","b","c"]` ?

Comment: @Timmy for `$3` enter: `a|b|c`

Comment: hmm...that gives me `<ul> <li>0 </li> </ul>`

Comment: you did not use a snippet but emmet

Comment: @Timmy where in the snippet is `<ul>`

Comment: here is my updated code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P2ESM0k8)

Comment: @Timmy You did not TAB out of $3 to $0

Comment: you are correct. now it works. thanks for your help

Comment: @Timmy Maybe an idea to swap $2 and $3 so you have to use TAB to get the snippet complete